# Strange lines when using `background-clip: text` on Safari

Tags: css, safari, linear-gradients, background-clip

I'm trying to make a gradient text using CSS. It currently works in Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari I get strange lines outside the border box.

My CSS looks like this...

```css
h1 {
    font-family: "Work Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.highlighted {
    color: transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF008B, #FF006B);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

My HTML is just a simple...

```html
<h1>Welcome to <span class="highlighted">My site</span></h1>
```

But on Safari it renders like this.

[image]

Can anyone help me fix those lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `clip-path` to fix it:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Work Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.highlighted {
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF008B, #FF006B);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
  padding: 1px;
  clip-path: inset(1px);
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to <span class="highlighted">My site</span></h1>
```

Comment: finally, found a fix for this, thnx